# Stop Super+M from opening Messaging Menu

Tags: 10.04, compiz, indicator, applet, messaging-menu

How can I make <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> work for compiz effects and not for indicator applet & indicator applet session in Lucid?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately the shortcuts for both indicator-applet and indicator-applet-session are **not** configurable, which causes problems. See bugs [#558581](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-applet/+bug/558581) and [#554713](https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-applet/+bug/554713).

If you are brave and know what you are doing, you could use one of the patches listed in bug report [#558581](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-applet/+bug/558581).

You could also use `indicator-applet-complete` which only uses the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> shortcut. See this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20903/override-built-in-maverick-keyboard-shortcuts/20908#20908) for more details.

Comment: thanks for showing me these bugs, i'll check out that patch soon

Answer (score 0):

You can change the key combination of each Compiz effect inside [CompizConfig Settings Manager.](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager)

Comment: thanks. yea, that's an option, but I'm used to the default shortcut keys and I don't need shortcuts for the indicator applet, etc.

Comment: Sorry for being blunt; I could have worded it better. I had to mess with the key combos when I enabled the plugins.