# Override Built-In Maverick Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: 10.10, keyboard, indicator, shortcut-keys, messaging-menu

Having used the <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> keyboard shortcut to minimize windows in OS X, I'd like to use the same functionality in Ubuntu 10.10. When I try, though, it only brings up the "communications" section of the indicator applet; like so:

[image]

In the *Keyboard Shortcuts* preferences, I have set as the minimize shortcut `Mod4+M`, which I got by capturing the Apple <kbd>Command</kbd> key and the <kbd>M</kbd> key. I find no other shortcut using this key combination in Keyboard Shortcuts, and yet I cannot get the window to minimize when using it.

Does anyone know how to override Ubuntu's default usage of this key combination? Thanks!

Comment: I can't get it to work the other way around (that is, I can't get my indicator applet to respond to keyboard shortcuts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it this bug? [Bug #558581](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-applet/+bug/558581)

It looks like an annoying race condition between programs that use global key bindings.

At that URL, Alex Beels wrote on 2011-01-05:

> To replace indicator-applet with indicator-applet-complete:,
>
> 1. Install indicator-applet-complete.
> 2. Remove both indicator-applet (the mail icon) and indicator-session (the on-off button) from the gnome panel.(Right click on icon, and choose "Remove From Panel" from the menu.)
> 3. Add indicator-applet-complete to the gnome panel. (Right click on panel background, and choose "Add to Panel..." from the menu.)

Answer (score 0):

> > It is simply learning something new.

Donato -- this is Linux.  One of the best things about it (and for myself, the main reason for using Linux) is the customization.  If you don't like something, you can change it.   There is no reason anything **has** to be any way.

It is a tradition in the Linux world to provide mechanism, not policy.  When keybindings are hardwired, it's an issue with the interface.  In a distro that holds polishing the interface so highly, this is inexcusable.

Comment: 'Inexcusable' seems a bit much.  Especially when the issue here was the result of the bug (with workaround given) described in @Christopher's answer.

Answer (score -1):

To minimize windows in Ubuntu,  use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>.  It is simply learning something new.