# How do I minimize all the windows using a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

Is there a keyboard shortcut to minimize all windows, like <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> on Windows?

Comment: how about minimizing the current active window?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

#### For 10.10, 13.10 and 17.10

<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is the default keyboard shortcut for minimizing all windows in Ubuntu 10.10.
You can change it to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> like it is in Windows using the *Keyboard Shortcuts* utility:
*System ➜ Preferences ➜ Keyboard Shortcuts*

[image]

**Note**: The keyboard shortcut <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> is used by both the Messaging Menu (see this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13751/stop-superm-from-opening-messaging-menu) for a solution) and the *Negative* Compiz plugin (You can disable or change its keyboard shortcuts by using
`compizconfig-settings-manager`).

Comment: In 10.04 and 11.04 ctrl-alt-d does this, weird that it got changed for 10.10 and then back.

Comment: no luck with CTRL+ALT+D on my Ubuntu 10.10 / 64 bits desktop. CTRL+ALT+L work to lock the screen though...

Comment: @BobYoplait Use SUPER (windows key) + D.

Comment: Got you, the message must have been edited because at first, it was CTRL+ALT. Thanks.

Comment: CTRL+ALT+D on Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: Windows key + D on Ubuntu 10.10

Comment: CTRL+SUPER+D in Ubuntu 14.

Comment: @AlvinRow The last image after "compizconfig-settings-manager" is broken, it returns "The image you are requesting does not exist or is no longer available"

Answer (score 36):

#### 12.04 and later

The keyboard shortcut to minimize all windows is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> in Ubuntu 12.04 and later.

Answer (score 20):

Simply press and hold <kbd>Super</kbd> key (which is generally the key with Windows logo on it) you will get list of all the shortcuts. In my Ubuntu 12.04 minimizing all windows in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: +1 for mentioning "Super key" corresponds to "Windows key"!

Answer (score 5):

Also, in 16.04 <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> works to show desktop / minimise all windows. When at desktop, same can be used to restore windows before show desktop.

Answer (score 3):

In my distro (Ubuntu 15.10), the shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

It was the same with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (From which I upgraded later).

Comment: in 14.04 it is CTRL+SUPER+D

Comment: It also works on ubuntu mate 16.04

Answer (score 2):

Summary of answers

10.04, 11.04: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

10.10, 13.10: <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

12.04, 14.04, 16.04, 18.04: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 20.04 you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to quickly minimize all windows and (if you haven't opened any windows since that) you can also un-minimize them by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> again.

Comment: Note: in Ubuntu Unity the "Show Desktop" button in the dock has to be enabled for Super+D to work as that. In some other linux distros it's also Super+D instead of Ctrl+Alt+D and Ctrl+Alt+D might not work in those distros.

Answer (score 0):

you can setting. go to Keyboard Shortcuts.

[image]

e.g.
Change <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>